# need to obtain this embossed geometry

Tags: modeling

I need to obtain a geometry similar tho this in picture. I am a beginer in Blender 3, looked in help files but could not figure out a way to obtain this geometry. It's a kind of a sketched emboss with constant depth in a curved surface. Tried to obtain it from mesh plane but couldn't. Please help.
[image: blender sketched emboss geometry]

Answer (score 2):

Begin with this shape:

[image]

Bevel the edge:

[image]

Cut some edges with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

Extrude these faces (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*):

[image]

Bevel the corner:

[image]

Add these edge loops with the knife:

[image]

Correct the topology like this:

[image]

Give a *Bevel* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object:

[image]